# if I have an array I want to open accordion Mui by map

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bzszt.png)  [enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bzszt.png)

This code is from MUI and look there please when you open the first accordion then you open the second accordion the first accordion is not closed. now I want to get the same functionality, but it doesn’t work for me when I do it through an array ( map ) then When I open the first accordion and then I want to open the second accordion, then the first accordion automatically closes for me, this is all due to the fact that I control the opening myself and closing by setExpanded. Please tell me how can I fix this so that I can open both the first and second accordions

```
const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(null)

  const handleChangeExpanded = (panel: string) => (event, newExpanded) => {
    setExpanded(newExpanded ? panel : false);
  };


  return (
    <Styled.Root>
        <form onSubmit={handleSaveOperation}>
              {operationsView?.map((operation, index) => {
                console.log('index', index);
                console.log('expanded', expanded);
                return (
                  <Accordion
                    key={operation.expenseId}
                    // expanded={expanded === `panel_${operation.expenseId}`}
                    onChange={handleChangeExpanded(`panel_${operation.expenseId}`)}
                  >
                    <AccordionSummary expandIcon={<SvgArrowFinancial />}>
                      <Grid css={pl(12)} container justifyContent="flex-start" alignItems="center">
                        <Grid item xs={0.3}>
                          <Controller
                            control={control}
                            name={`selections.${index}`}
                            render={({ field: { value, onChange } }) => (
                              <FormControlLabel
                                value={value}
                                onChange={(e, checked) => onChange(checked)}
                                css={labelTextCSS}
                                control={<Checkbox />}
                                label=""
                              />
                            )}
                          />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={2.34}>
                          <Typography css={[operationsDataCSS, centerTextCSS]}>{operation.dateOfPayment}</Typography>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={2.66}>
                          <Grid container justifyContent="flex-start" alignItems="center">
                            <Grid item xs={7.9}>
                              <Typography
                                css={
                                  expanded === `panel_${operation.expenseId}`
                                    ? [operationsDataCSS, ml(8)]
                                    : [operationsDataBoldCSS, ml(8)]
                                }
                              >
                                {operation.dateOfReceive}
                              </Typography>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid css={successIconCSS} item xs={4.1}>
                              {operation.excluded ? <SvgWarningIcon /> : <SvgSuccessIcon />}
                            </Grid>
                          </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={3.82}>
                          <Typography
                            css={
                              expanded === `panel_${operation.expenseId}`
                                ? [operationsDataBoldCSS, ml(16)]
                                : [operationsDataCSS, ml(16)]
                            }
                          >
                            {operation.contractor}
                          </Typography>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={2.26}>
                          <Typography
                            css={[
                              expanded === `panel_${operation.expenseId}` ? operationsDataBoldCSS : operationsDataCSS,
                              textRightCSS,
                            ]}
                          >
                            {operation.money}
                          </Typography>
                        </Grid>
                      </Grid>
                    </AccordionSummary>
                    <AccordionDetails>
                      <Grid container justifyContent="space-between" flexDirection="column">
                        <Grid item xs={11.35}>
                          <Grid container justifyContent="center" alignItems="start">
                            <Grid item xs={5.7}></Grid>
                            <Grid item xs={3.8}>
                              <Typography css={operationsChildDataCSS}>
                                На сумму {operation.money} в том числе НДС 18%
                              </Typography>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item xs={2.14}>
                              <Typography css={[operationsChildDataCSS, textRightCSS]}>По счёту</Typography>
                            </Grid>
                          </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid></Grid>
                      </Grid>
                    </AccordionDetails>
                  </Accordion>
                );
              })}
            </Grid>
            <Grid
              css={[pr(24), mt(15)]}
              gap={2}
              container
              justifyContent="flex-end"
              flexDirection="row"
              alignItems="center"
            >
              <Grid>
                <Typography css={textAddingSumCSS}>Дополнительно:</Typography>
              </Grid>
              <Grid>
                <Controller
                  name="sum"
                  control={control}
                  render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
                    <TextField
                      css={addingSumCSS}
                      onChange={onChange}
                      value={value}
                      color="primary"
                      variant="outlined"
                      placeholder="0,00"
                      fullWidth
                      InputProps={{
                        inputComponent: CurrencyInput,
                      }}
                    />
                  )}
                />
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Grid
              css={[pr(52), mt(30)]}
              gap={2}
              container
              justifyContent="flex-end"
              flexDirection="row"
              alignItems="center"
            >
              <Grid>
                <Typography css={totalSumTextCSS}>Итоговая сумма:</Typography>
              </Grid>
              <Grid css={totalSumCSS}>{sumItems}</Grid>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </form>
      </MuiDrawer>
    </Styled.Root>
  );
};

  [1]: https://codesandbox.io/s/td9gs4?file=/demo.tsx
```

Answer (score 0):

> When I open the first accordion and then I want to open the second
> accordion, then the first accordion automatically closes for me, this
> is all due to the fact that I control the opening myself and closing
> by `setExpanded`.

You already figured out the problem. So just use the simple accordion functionality as in the sandbox that you shared. You can remove `expanded` and `onChange` for the `<Accordion />` component and you will the same functionality as you expected.

Here is the simple sandbox rendered with your data.

[image: Edit BasicAccordion Material Demo (forked)]

Comment: I can't do that because when I open it I need to change the font and color of the text

Comment: Okay. You can have `onChange` for `Accordion`, that'll give you whether the accordion is expanded or not. Based on that, you can apply your styles. I think you can remove just the `expanded` flag. I have updated the sandbox. Check once whether that is what you are expecting.

Comment: To be honest, I didn't understand how to do it.

Comment: how can i delete expanded flag

Comment: ```<Accordion eventKey={operationData.id} key={operationData.id} onChange={handleChangeExpanded(`panel_${operationData.id}`)}>```
Don't pass the prop to that component.

Comment: thank you very much, but here is the question. how to understand what exactly this accordion is open, I need a condition if this accordion is open then change the color

Comment: `
                        <Typography
                          css={
                            expanded === `panel_${index - 1}`
                              ? [operationsDataBoldCSS, ml(16)]
                              : [operationsDataCSS, ml(16)]
                          }
                        >
                          {operation.contractor}
                        </Typography>`

Comment: Understood. So you need to maintain a unique identifier to identify which accordion is opened. As per your requirement, you can open as many as accordions that are present.

Comment: You already using the `expanded` flag. Why can't you use the same thing?
Even in the sandbox also, I used the same flag and updated the color. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: can you suggest how to do it

Comment: Check the attached sandbox. I have also used the `expanded` flag and updated the content items. Your case is the same. Just use the `expanded` only for ```expanded ? operationsDataCSS : operationsDataBoldCSS```

Comment: but when I do this, when opening 1 accordion, the styles change for all

Comment: you can't tell me how to do it

Comment: Sorry man. Got busy and didn't check this. I have understood you and it's good to maintain a state variable for each accordion item. I have updated the sandbox. Check once.

Comment: I have edited my code. It seems to me that I wrote the same thing, but for some reason it hasn’t been working for me for 3 days

Comment: Can you try to share a reproducible sandbox with the exact styles that you want?

Comment: when the accordion is open, the font inside my accordion changes bold ....... font - family : bold

Comment: when i close accordion 2 it thinks the first accordion is also closed

Comment: i am adding image

Comment: I'm sorry I keep you so long

Comment: Check the sandbox in my answer. I updated it with a bold style also. The content is updated with bold only when it is expanded. I have also updated the header style too. You can try with the same concept.

Comment: thank you very much, I made accordions a separate component and everything worked out for me